# Leksah does not show any modules

Tags: haskell, leksah

I have installed Leksah 0.12.0.3 on Windows 8 in `C:\Leksah` and the latest Haskell Platform in `C:\HaskellPlatform`.

I created a new workspace and package and added a module of my own (distinct from the `Main` one that Leksah creates). I can import and use this new module in the Main module, however Leksah does not show it in the right Browser pane no matter what I do - it only lists the Main module there. If I switch to System, that list is empty.

I have tried:

- reinstalling Leksah and the Haskell Platform;
- running `ghc-pkg recache` in a `cmd` ran as admin;
- putting my workspace and package in paths without spaces.

Still, no luck. Also, in the console that opens along with Leksah, I see this when my workspace / package open:

```
Using default Yi configuration
Warning: D:\Haskell\TestPackage\TestPackage.cabal: A package using section
syntax must specify at least
'cabal-version: >= 1.2'.
Now updating system metadata ...
***server start
Bind 127.0.0.1:26411
Metadata collector has nothing to do
Metadata collection has finished
Now loading metadata ...
Now updating workspace metadata ...
Can't extract module C:\Users\Vlad\.leksah-0.12\metadata\TestPackage-1\Test.lksh
e <command line>: cannot satisfy -package -db
    (use -v for more information)
Finished
>>>Info Changed!!! True
```

Also, under Configuration -> Edit Prefs -> Metadata, "Paths under which haskell sources for packages may be be found" is empty. Should I put something there, and if yes, what?

I don't know what to try anymore. How can I get Leksah working right?

Comment: @MJP - I "fixed" it by switching to Eclipse FP: http://eclipsefp.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had someone suggest that your leksah needs to be compiled with the same version of GHC as the one you have on your system. I haven't tried it, but even if it's true, I think that is really silly and shows that leksah may not be mature enough yet, at least not for my comfort. Not to mention that this could easily be detected and the user notified.

So, I ended up using [Eclipse FP](http://eclipsefp.github.io/), which works great.